# Как разбить число на несколько по несколько символов в каждом?

Tags: javascript

Допустим, у нас есть число 12345678, нужно разбить его на массив из нескольких чисел по 3 символа в каждом начиная с конца, если количество символов в нашем числе не кратно 3-м, то короче должен быть первый элемент массива, то есть в результате должно получится 12,345,678.

Comment: оо, очень выручили, большое вам спасибо! сам тож решил свою задачу, но у меня совсем велосипед получился)

Comment: Это вы еще просто не встречались с "действительно сложными задачами" =) Данная задача проста. Все "негладкости" заключаются лишь в том, что количество цифр может быть не кратно 3.

Answer (score 15):

Самый лаконичный вариант :-)

```
s="1234567890";
result= s.split( /(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/ ); // [1, 234, 567, 890]
```

Comment: O___o наверно никогда не перестану удивляться тому, что можно сделать с помощью RegExp`ов

Comment: Можно немного упростить: `/(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/`

Comment: Нихрена, всего две строчки! =)

Comment: @Salivan если не создавать глобальную переменную, то можно и одной обойтись

var result = '1234567890'.split(/(?=(?:\d{3})+$)/); // [1, 234, 567, 890]

Answer (score 6):

Слышал `unshift` не во всех реализациях js быстро работает, но зато простое лаконичное решение:

```
var a = 12345678..toString().split(''),
    result = [], 
    start;
while((start = a.length - 3) > 0){
    result.unshift(a.splice(start, 3));
} 
result.unshift(a);
console.log(result); // [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
```

---

> нужно разбить его на массив из нескольких чисел по 3 символа

неправильно понял вопрос, вот более верное решение:

```
var a = 12345678..toString(),
    result = [], 
    start = a.length,
    end;
while((end = start) > 0){
    start = end - 3;
    result.unshift(~~a.substring(start, end));
    // result = [~~a.substring(start, end)].concat(result); // возможно быстрее
}
console.log(result); // [12, 345, 678]
```

- [Array unshift method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)
- [Array splice method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
- [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

Answer (score 4):

И еще один взгляд на вещи:

```
function divide(number, digits) {
    var result = [];
    var interm = [];
    var counter = 1;
    while(number >= 1) {
        mod = number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
        interm.unshift(parseInt(mod));
        if(!(counter % digits)) {
            result.unshift(interm);
            interm = [];
        }
        counter++;
    }
    result.unshift(interm);
    console.log(result.join('\n'));
}
```

Изящного тоже мало, правда, не пробовал себя еще в JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

И еще вариант :)

```
function triades(n){
  var x=parseInt(n,10).toString();
  var r=/(\d+)(\d{3})/;
  while(r.test(x)){
    x=x.replace(r,'$1,$2');
  };
  return x.split(',');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Вот я тоже решил написать специальную функцию:**

(Это, конечно же, не так изящненько, как вариант [[@Spectre](/users/3159/spectre)](/users/3159/spectre), но все же, логика работы совсем другая).

```
function simple_splitter(dig)
{
var array = [],
    mask = dig.toString(),
    key = (mask.length)%3,
    first_sp = (key==0) ? 3:key,
    i = 0;
while(mask.length>3)
{
    var sub_str, k;
    k = (i==0) ? first_sp:3;
    sub_str = mask.substr(0,k);
    array.push(sub_str);
    mask = mask.substr(k,mask.length-k);
    if(mask.length == 3) {array.push(mask); break;}
    i++;
    }
return array;
}
```

Если выкинуть все лишнее, то код станет немного короче. Применение:

```
var virtual_digit = 1234567;
arr = new Array();
arr = simple_splitter(virtual_digit);
alert(arr.toString());  // [1,234,567]
```

Comment: пара замечаний:

- используйте [Single var Pattern](https://github.com/shichuan/javascript-patterns/blob/master/general-patterns/single-var-pattern.html)
- используйте литералы вместо конструкторов:

    - [Primitive Wrappers](https://github.com/shichuan/javascript-patterns/blob/master/literals-and-constructors/primitive-wrappers.html)
    - [Array literal](https://github.com/shichuan/javascript-patterns/blob/master/literals-and-constructors/array-literal.html)

Comment: Благодарю, @Spectre! Полностью согласен, что "var`ов" я переналяпал. С используемыми конструкторами массива и строки тоже согласен - они здесь явно лишние. Но их я использовал умышленно, для большей наглядности.

Answer (score 2):

Из одного проекта:

```
function fixNumber(n){
    var s = n.toString().split('.');
    var r = '';
    for(var i = s[0].length-3; i > 0; i-=3)
        r = s[0].substr(i, 3) + ' ' + r;
    r = s[0].substr(0, i+3) + ' ' + r;
    r = r.substr(0, r.length-1);
    s[1] = s[1] || '00';
    return r+'.'+s[1];
}
```