# Преобразование числового значения в строку с разделителем

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Беру строковое значение из `.amount`, преобразую его в числовое значение, делаю определенные с ним действия и хочу снова преобразовать его в текст, но не знаю как добавить точку после каждого тысячного порядка. Для упрощения сделал вариант с возвращением к первоначальному виду.

Зачем понадобилось приводить к числовому виду и убирать точку? Затем, что при умножении строки с разделителем в JavaScript обрезается порядок, что мне абсолютно не нужно.

```js
function parseNumber(str) {
  var regExp = /\d+/g;
  var part;
  var result = 0;
  while (part = regExp.exec(str)) {
    result = result * Math.pow(10, part[0].length) + parseInt(part[0]);
  }
  return result;
}
var quantity = $(".quantity").text().match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g);
quantity[1] = parseNumber(quantity[1]);
$(".amount2").text((quantity[0] * quantity[1]) + " руб");
$(".quantity2")[0].firstChild.data = quantity[0] + " × ";
```

```html
<span class="quantity">1 × <span class="amount">120.000 руб</span></span>
<span class="quantity2">1 × <span class="amount2">120000 руб</span></span>
```

Comment: Не знаю- дубль это, или нет. Смотрите http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/140472/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc/140551#140551 там найдете как разбить число на разряды по тысячам.

Comment: @ReinRaus спасибо, буду смотреть, но это ни разу не дубль! у меня число с умножением, с "руб" и еще притом должно записаться правильно в спан - мой вариант посложнее

Comment: смысл абсолютно тот же. Разделить на тысячные порядки. В том, чтобы записать потом в спан нет никакой сложности. Это было бы наоборот мусорным кодом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript) советуют нетривиальное регулярное выражение:

```
function numberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

В этом примере тысячи отделяют запятыми. Ещё подводный камень – если после десятичной точки/запятой больше 3 знаков, это решение вставит запятые и там. Чтобы этого не было, можно бить на части входное значение, и обрабатывать только первую часть:

```
function numberWithCommas(n) {
    var parts=n.toString().split(".");
    return parts[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + (parts[1] ? "." + parts[1] : "");
}
```

Comment: Весьма занятное регулярное выражение.